# Flutter streambuilder (firebase) fade in

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having an app with multiple screens, (pageView + cupertino tabbar). Within a few pages, I use a streambuilder. Just like this

```
class BookList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('books').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Loading...');
          default:
            return new ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(document['title']),
                  subtitle: new Text(document['author']),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Everything works, but when I switch pages (yes, i'm already using the keep client alive mixing). There's half a second 'nothing' and then the streambuilder comes. But I would like to make it more 'gentle' by using a fade animation everytime the streambuilder is done loading.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Firebase, StreamBuilder and presenting an animation while updating/receiving data are 3 complete different things.

Comment: Yes, but the data comes from firebaase, and I would like to know if theres an option to do the animation?

Answer (score 2):

Whichever be the source of data(Firebase) you just need to wrap the top-most widget with an `AnimatedSwitcher` inside the `StreamBuilder`'s builder property to achieve that fade-in animation.

```
class BookList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('books').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return new AnimatedSwitcher(
             duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
             child: snapshot.hasData?Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}')):Container();
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Loading...');
          default:
            return new ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(document['title']),
                  subtitle: new Text(document['author']),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```